# What text file is the layout netlist stored as?

Tags: analog, layout

I know that a analog schematic is converted to SPICE format to give a .cdl or .sp file netlist.
How does a layout of the same schematic get converted to a text file? What is this format? I am using Cadence Virtuoso ADE.

I know that post layout simulations are done with the same testbench but with a DSPF file after the RC extraction. Is there no "layout netlist" file?

Comment: Just generate a net-list and see what new file is created.

Comment: Is the layout netlist == the dspf extraction .spf file? I don't know any other file related to layout.

Comment: In the olden days we used GDS2 files. I don't think they have a textual format, though.

Answer (score 0):

I did some investigation with my colleagues in layout and found out that once the layout is ready, the OASIS file (with a .oas extension) contains all the text information about the layout.

This file will be used for further stages to check like LVS (layout vs schematic) and to generate the extraction data (.spf)